# R: How to validate the model performance of the `rmweather' package?

Tags: r, validation, random-forest, cross-validation

i am relatively inexperienced in using R. I was looking for a weather normalizing technique and came across the package "rmweather".

I have run the model and am now not sure how I evaluate this. I test an overfitting with the 'rmw_predict_the_test_set' function. This will run the model with the test dataset.

I would like to do a cross validation. Do I need to compare the model statistics (rmw_model_statistics) with the test results? I get the error that my model is not a "ranger" model.

0

More Details:

i would like to study the effects of the COVID-19-virus containment measures on air quality. I have meteorological data for 4 years. The dataset "data_prepared" is spilt in 80 % training and 20% test. I have trained the model with data from 2017-2019 and would like to perform a weather normalization for 2020.

First I used the function:

```
 RF_pm2.5_model <- "rmw_do_all(
      data_prepared,
      variables = c("date_unix", "day_julian", "weekday", "hour", "temp", "RH", "wd", "ws", "pressure","u.","L","MLH"),
variables_sample=c("hour", "temp", "RH", "wd", "ws", "pressure","u.","L","MLH"), 
      n_trees = 500,
      n_samples = 500,
      verbose = TRUE)"
```

I would like the check the modelperformance with crossvalidation. I found the option to check if the model has suffered from overfitting:

```
testing_model <- rmw_predict_the_test_set(model = RF_pm2.5_model$model,
                                          df = RF_pm2.5_model$observations) 
model_performance<-modStats(testing_model, mod = "value", obs = "value_predict", 
                            statistic = c("n", "FAC2","MB", "MGE", "NMB", "NMGE", "RMSE","COE", "IOA", "r"), type = "default", rank.name = NULL)
```

But i am not sure, how to compare it to the performance for the training dataset.

Comment: please, add your data and bring some examples to the discussion

Comment: ["ranger"](https://github.com/imbs-hl/ranger) is an R package that implements the "Random Forest" (RF) Machine Learning algorithm. It is relatively new, and faster than many older packages for RF.